# Is there a formalised high-level notation for Pseudocode?

Tags: pseudocode, language-design, apl

I'd like to be able to reason about code on paper better than just writing boxes or pseudocode.

The key thing here is **paper**. On a machine, I can most likely use a high-level language with a linter/compiler very quickly, and a keyboard restricts what can be done, somewhat.

A case study is APL, a language that we semi-jokingly describe as "write-only". Here is an [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_(programming_language)#Design):

`m ← +/3+⍳4`

(Explanation: `⍳4` creates an array, `[1,2,3,4]`, then 3 is added to each component, which are then summed together and the result stored in variable m.)

Look how concise that is! Imagine having to type those symbols in your day job! But, writing iota and arrows on a whiteboard is fine, saves time and ink.

Here's its haskell equivalent:

`m = foldl (+) 0 (map (+3) [1..4])`

And Python:

`reduce(add, map(lambda x: x+3, range(4)))`

But the principle behind these concise programming languages is different: they use words and punctuation to describe high-level actions (such as `fold`), whereas I want to write symbols for these common actions.

Does such a formalised pseudocode exist?

Comment: Thanks in advance, guys!

Comment: If it's so that you can use it for yourself, wouldn't it be easier to invent your own notation, that fits exactly to your domain and your mode of thinking, than to learn a notation invented by someone else?

Comment: Just being curious (and I only know APL): are the Python and Haskell-Samples really equivalent? Where's the `3` in that code? (And BTW, I fully agree with Evans: APL seems to be the best answer, especially if you are looking for symbols instead of words)

Comment: Oh! well spotted, will update the examples, thank you

Comment: @svick you're not the only person to give me this advice...

Comment: Oh BTW, I only just spotted a way to further shorten the APL-Code: `m←+/3+⍳4`. No parantheses needed, as APL will process from right to left anyway ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Not to be snarky, but you could use APL. It was after all originally invented as a mathematical notation before it was turned into a programming language. I seem to remember that there was something like what I think you are talking about in Backus' Turing Award lecture. Finally, maybe Z Notation is what you want: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_notation

Comment: I think the problem with using APL or Z is that it's not the right domain for, say, reasoning about a webapp.

Comment: Hmm, sorry, but I don't see the problem. Whether you output to console, to a Windows-Form or HTML should not make such a difference on the pseudo-code level. Aren't algorithms and flow of data etc. the main concern there?

Comment: BTW, you can of course also develop web-applications with most/all flavours of APL - the one I know and like best is http://miserver.dyalog.com - Dyalog APL is free for personal use :)